# I upvoted a comment, but the upvote arrow doesn't show it

Tags: bug, comments, voting, up-votes

I upvoted a comment, but the upvote arrow doesn't show it.

Demo:

[image]

Only once I refreshed the page the upvote arrow showed my upvote:

[image]

Comment from the demo gif: [How can I tell whether a jackfruit has yellow or orange flesh by looking at the exterior of the jackfruit (i.e., without opening it)?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/116070/how-can-i-tell-whether-a-jackfruit-has-yellow-or-orange-flesh-by-looking-at-the#comment187309_116070)

It happened to me a few times. The issue happens even on a stable Internet connection and not necessarily when switching VPN. The issue happens even when not using the web browser's back button (i.e., the issue may happen when staying on the same page).

Tested on Chrome Version 91.0.4472.101 (Official Build) (64-bit) + Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Hmm, no repro here on Chrome Version 91.0.4472.101. What browser are ya using?

Comment: @Spevacus also chrome, the bug doesn't happen frequently

Comment: Can you rule out interruptions in your internet connection? I sometimes experience similar symptoms when I have a bad connection.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I was in a skype call then and I didn't notice any connection issues.

Comment: Repro here, same chrome and firefox 89 X64 bit win 10. It seemed to start around the time of subscribing to a VPN.

Comment: I believe it happens if you navigate away from the page, but then change your mind and navigate back with the browser's back-button. When using the browser's "back button", the entire page shows how it looked initially on the most recent full page-load; that excludes all the modifications that your recent interactions caused. Only a page-refresh can bring the interactive parts up-to-date with how they should look.

Comment: This is true also to comments you had made. You make a comment, navigate to another page, use the browser's back-button to come back, and your comment is nowhere to be seen. Again, you need to refresh the page to see the current state of the comment-related interactive parts.

Comment: It's @Levente's comment:  Using the back button confuses it and throws the error.  Happens with question-voting buttons as well.

Comment: This bug has happened to me, and it's extremely frustrating because when you try to click it again, it un-upvotes, then you can ***never upvote again***.

Comment: @user1271772 It should be warning you that you're about to remove the upvote. That's actually a bug if it's not asking for confirmation about your vote first.

Comment: @BSMP Maybe it did warn me but since the arrow was not changing color, I did it anyway because I thought I'd need to un-upvote then re-upvote, but unfortunately, you can't re-upvote, which is something ***they do not warn you about***. This happened to me multiple times, but rarely enough that I didn't remember not to un-upvote (well also I didn't know that refreshing the page solves the problem, so I might have even known that I was un-upvoted but felt I had no other choice). The bug described by the OP, an the bug "by design" of not allowing people to re-upvote comments, are both terrible.

Comment: @user1271772 _"but unfortunately, you can't re-upvote, which is something they do not warn you about"_ [Yes, they do](https://i.imgur.com/lLt8IgT.png).

Comment: @41686d6564 I stand corrected. But I stand by the fact that this is a bug "by design", and when you're confused as to why your upvote didn't seem to count (the color of the arrow didn't change, and the number beside the comment didn't increase), you can't blame yourself for not fully grasping that warning message.

Comment: @user1271772 Well, yeah, that's the issue that the OP is reporting. I personally never encountered this _without navigating from the page_ except when I had connection issues. Your mileage may vary though.

Comment: @Ollie It doesn't "confuse it". The browser just loads a cached version of the page (could be missing votes, comments, answers, etc.). The same thing happens when you close the page and then use "Reopen closed tab" (at least on Chrome).